# Why do you divide bit depth by 8 when computing PCM file size?

Tags: audio, size, wav, pcm

So basically, I thought the formula for computing pcm file size went as follows:

```
fileSize(in bits) = samples_per_sec x seconds x number_of_channels
```

And it worked just fine for me since I was exclusively dealing with pcm files which had 8 bit depth.
When I started to deal with 16 bit depth files, the formula didn't produce accurate results.
Through some googling I found out that my aformentioned formula was wrong, actually you have to adhere to this one:

```
fileSize(in bits) = samples_per_sec x seconds x number_of_channel x bit_depth/8
```

It explains why I was getting correct results with the incorrect formula since, you know, 8 / 8 = 1.

The thing that I don't get is this: why do you have to divide bit depth by eight?
In order to get bits as a result of your calculations, you have to get them on the right side of your formula as well:

```
bits = samples/seconds x seconds x  num_of_channels(dimensionless) x bits/sample = bits
```

which is fine. So, it should work without division by eight. But it doesn't.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: by `num_of_channels(dimensionless)` do you mean that `num_of_channels` has no units or something else entirely?

Comment: @fdcpp Yeah, I mean that it has no units

Comment: lovely, in that case my answer stands as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your notation style:

- `samples_per_sec x seconds x number_of_channels` is **total number of samples**
- `samples_per_sec x seconds x number_of_channel x bit_depth` is **total number of bits**
- `samples_per_sec x seconds x number_of_channel x bit_depth / 8` is **total number of *bytes***
- `samples/seconds x seconds x num_of_channels(dimensionless) x bits/sample` is `sample_rate x duration_in_seconds x num_of_channels x bit_depth`, which is again **total number of bits**

The main confusion is likely from *bits* and *bytes*. Audio sample size is typically described in ***bit* depth** not ***byte* depth**. File size / memory is described typically in *bytes*. To go from *bits* to *bytes* you simply divide by 8.

Comment: Appaently all methods of my script that deal with file sizes output that in bytes, that's why it worked for me. Many thanks